# c# 8.0 switch expression return type and null value

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, switch-expression

I'm trying to understand how C# 8.0 switch expressions work and have got several questions.

1. Why is it not possible to use `null` value in the default case? The compiler throws `Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type` error.
2. Why is it trying to convert the null value to `int` whereas the function's return type is 'double?'?

Here is the function I'm playing with:

```
public static double? SwitchFunction(int x) =>
    x switch
    {
        1 => 1,
        _ => null
    };
```

Comment: Try casting the result of the switch to `double?`.  None of the `switch` responses are of type `double?`.

Comment: It's similar to how `var x = condition ? 1 : null;` doesn't work because the compiler isn't quite smart enough to know that you want a `int?`.

Comment: The compiler infers the 'int' type from the first case where you return an int value (1).  The result from that switch will only be cast to a double? upon returning from the call.

Comment: `var x = condition ? 1 : (double)null;`  will work however.

Comment: @JasonInVegas `Cannot convert null to 'double' because it is a non-nullable value type`

Comment: use ```_ => default(double?)``` instead

Comment: ya     that   that's what I meant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a switch expression, all possible values must be (implicitly castable to) the same type. Because your first case is `1 => 1,` and you don't cast the integer literal to a type other than `int`, the rest of the cases will be assumed to be `int` as well. You'll need to cast that 1 to `(double?)` to have the compiler interpret the rest of the cases also as `double?`, a nullable type - that will solve both of your points.

Answer (score 2):

You're hitting a problem that is commonly encountered in the conditional expression.

```
// Compiler Error CS0173
// Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because 
// there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and '<null>'
//
// var d2 = i == 1 ? 1 : null; 

// This works
var d2 = i == 1 ? 1 : (double?) null;
```

To address the issue in the `switch` expression you can help the compiler by specifying the type the `null` is.

```
int i = 2;
var d = i switch
{
    1 => 1,
    _ => (double?)null
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem resulting in a different error message: "No best type was found for the switch expression".

```
var isRequired = someIntValue switch
    {
      0 => null,
      1 => false,
      2 => true,
      _ => throw new NotSupportedException(),
    };
```

I couldn't understand this error message until I read the answers here. The compiler cannot figure out what the type of isRequired should be. My intention was bool?. Changing the code to this makes the error message disappear:

```
var isRequired = someIntValue switch
    {
      0 => (bool?)null,
      1 => false,
      2 => true,
      _ => throw new NotSupportedException(),
    };
```

On the other hand, I could just tell the compiler what I want:

```
bool? isRequired = someIntValue switch
    {
      0 => null,
      1 => false,
      2 => true,
      _ => throw new NotSupportedException(),
    };
```

I read on GitHub that they intend to fix this in a future version.